# Android Ndk Basic regarding Native String

Tags: android, android-ndk

To learn basic practice presence am calling string to my application. I know its too basic but am new to native languages. Like:

```
  jstring Java_com_idiasoft_LoginActivity_NdkdealerName(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis)
     {

         return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "User Name");

     }
```

Here I can call this string in particular  class. But I wanna make dynamic call. like two or more classes. where am uses the same string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a perfect solution regarding NDK but I think creating a global class in Java part could help you in this situation.
Just define that particular native function in your global class and use it anywhere.
If there is no need to instantiate the class you can also make it static and use it anywhere in your application.
Hope this helps.

Comment: lol! Actually am using in a such way. looking for quite optimization. Looking for dynamic call from ndk itself. anyhow thank for your reply.